# how to set the custom layout to the bottom of every activity

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to add the buttons to the bottom of each activity through include tag. but it is not aligning with bottom. its about in the center. following is the xml which I am including in my bottom of other activity;

bottom_buttton_bar

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="9"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:text="abc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/bbb"
        android:text="bbb"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

so what is wrong in it. How can I tackle it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property to the include tag in your layout file (providing it is using a `RelativeLayout` as parent, which I would suggest to use)

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
    layout="@layout/your_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```